# Some property object are null

Tags: symfony

I have a problem and of course i dont understand :) (and of course im french :)

On a table "evenement" i have a user linked.
And When i do :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Evenement');
$evt = $repository->findOneById($evt);
dump($evt)
```

All is ok, i can read my evt, but when in profiler i click on a child object "user", all property are null (except id, usermail, mail, password)

and its the same thing when i do :

```
dump($evt->getUser());
```

Why all property are not filled ?

thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably [Lazy Loading](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/05/29/doctrine-lazy-loading.html). Properties are not beeing read from DB unless you need them.

Try to do the following:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Evenement');
$evt = $repository->findOneById($evt);
$evt->getUser()->getRoles(); // Ot whatever properties your user has.
dump($evt)
```

In this case, dump will show this property populated.

Comment: yeah that's worked if i do dump($evenement->getUser()->getCodePostal()); : ! but how i can populated all property in only one time?

Comment: Why would you need it? Just to inspect it through dump?

Comment: just put object in session for use in twig, by example {{ app.session.get('evt').user.email }}

Comment: Then just don't worry. When you will use data, it will be there. Until that moment - it will not. It's the essence of lazy loading - to save resources and to load only those data which is used in application